# How do I remember who I've dated?

Tags: the-sims-2

<sub>Well, I went to the doctor and found out... nah...</sub>

In the Sims 2, one of the aspirations your Sim can have is the Pleasure aspiration, and the lifetime goal for it is to have 50 first dates.

Is there any way in-game to find out who you've been on a date with, or at least how many first dates you've had?

Comment: Do they show up in your sim's memories?

Comment: @Kaestur yes, along with every other thing ever recorded in the game. After a while, it becomes extremely tedious and inefficient to scroll through all the memories, and I'm not sure how far back memories even go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only ingame interface is within the Sim's memories.

I believe that [SimPE](http://sims.ambertation.de/index.shtml), a third party editor is also able to read the data file, but it's unlikely to give any more information than the memories screen.